# HTML center on middle img and menu

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a work for school and I'm trying to align on center and middle both image and a menu. Here is my code on jsfiddle: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/mebxcjwx/1/) I'll post the code here too

**HTML**

```
<header>

<img id="logo" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300.jpg">
<ul id="menutop1">
    <li><a href="#home">Loja</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background-color: #171A21;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center; 
}
#logo{
 width: 250px;
 height: 172px;
}

#menutop1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#menutop1 li {
    float: left;
}

#menutop1 li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menutop1 li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

The problem is the menu that does under the image and stays on left of the page.
I already tried everything I know and I didn't find a solution, please someone can help me? I realy can't find anything.

Thanks for the help and sorry for my english.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the Kamila O the menu is next to the image and now I want center on middle, I added this code:

```
vertical-align: middle; height: 100%;
```

on the menu but don't think it is the best soluction becouse when I set a background color on the menu just to test I see this:

[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/mebxcjwx/12/)

the menu get out of the div. Someone know a better soluction?

Comment: Are you trying to get the menu centered below the image in that header tag?

Comment: @factordog I want the image and the menu center in middle but the menu is next to the image.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @Azazel if you see my answer is that correct? :)

Comment: @factordog I already look your aswer but as I said I want the menu next to the image, see my main question the update part, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center your menu, you can change #menutop1 li to

```
#menutop1 li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks is that what I want, it is possivel to set the menu in the middle of the div?

Comment: Ok to center the menu in the middle I used `vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;` don't know if is the best to use becouse when I puta a background color on the menu to see where he goes, the color get out of the div

Comment: no I want both in center on middle see my main quetion on the update

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have added a float: left on the individual list items in the menu.

If you remove that float, make the list items inline-block and add a center text-align to #menutop1, it will align properly.

```
#menutop1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;   
    text-align: center;
}

#menutop1 li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Updated jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/mebxcjwx/4/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote quickly something along the lines of this. I just created containers for your logo + navigation, as this allows for you to control elements a bit better. As well as adding tha  tag around your ul element.

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
      <img  src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300.jpg">
  </div>
  <nav class="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mebxcjwx/9/

Because they take up the full width of the header by default (If you want you can set this as display: block or width 100%) they will stack under each other, and since they are text elements all that was needed was a simple text align center to get the desired effect.

Im not sure if you wanted the navigation in the black space, if not you could simple remove the padding on the header, and give that navigation a white background or something along those lines to get the effect you desired!